# Different results of Engle's Lagrange multiplier test for conditional heteroscedasticity from SAS and FinTS

Tags: r, time-series, sas, heteroscedasticity, autoregressive

To fit a simple AR(5) model, I use SAS `PROC AUTOREG`.  I called the option `ARCHTEST=(QLM)` which provides Engle’s Lagrange Multiplier Test for ARCH Disturbances and the Portmanteau Q Test.  The statistics SAS provided for Engle’s Lagrange Multiplier Test were:

```
Order   LM      p-value
1       0.018   0.893
2       0.079   0.961
3       0.881   0.830
4       1.088   0.896
5       1.105   0.954
6       4.114   0.661
7       4.179   0.759
8       4.182   0.840
9       4.528   0.873
10      4.528   0.920
11      5.565   0.901
12      6.318   0.899
```

I took the residuals of this model and used the `ArchTest` function of the `FinTS` package of `R` ... `library(FinTS)`.

```
# A function to do ArchTest at multiple lags where 'data' are the residuals of
# the model.
library(FinTS) 
arch.m1 = matrix(NaN,12,3)
for(i in 1:12)  {s = ArchTest(data,lags=i)
                 arch.m1[i,1] = s$statistic
                 arch.m1[i,2] = s$parameter
                 arch.m1[i,3] = s$p.value}
```

The test results from the `ArchTest` function of the `FinTS` package are very different:

```
Order   LM      p-value
1       0.014   0.907
2       0.092   0.955
3       0.835   0.841
4       2.194   0.700
5       3.189   0.671
6       13.013  0.043
7       19.157  0.008
8       23.161  0.003
9       18.780  0.027
10      18.467  0.048
11      22.565  0.020
12      23.828  0.021
```

I thought the SAS `ARCHTEST=(QLM)` option and the `ArchTest` function of the `FinTS` package were performing the same test but apparently not.  Does anyone know what the difference is between the tests in SAS and `FinTS`?

**Note**, the data used by Tsay (2005) in the example on page 102 is available [here](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/fts2/m-intc7303.txt).

Using the following `R` code:

```
library(FinTS)
intc=read.table("http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/fts2/m-intc7303.txt", quote="\"")
ArchTest(intc$V2,lags=12)
```

I find:

$\chi^2$= 48.0425, df = 12, *p*-value = 3.073e-06

However, Tsay (2005:102) reports:

$\chi^2$= 43.5041, df = 12, *p*-value = 0.0000

If I use:

```
ArchTest(log(1+intc$V2),lags=12)
```

Then:

$\chi^2$= 43.5041, df = 12, *p*-value = 0.0000

However, this doesn't explain the differences observed between SAS and `FinTS`.

**Thanks for your reply @mpiktas.**

The statistic calculated by the `FinTS library` using the `ArchTest function` is based on the second statistic provided by @mpiktas:

$$TR^2=T\left(1-\frac{SSR_1}{SSR_0}\right)$$

```
intc=read.table("http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/fts2/m-intc7303.txt",quote="\"")
intc.ln=log(1+intc$V2)
lag=12
mat=embed(intc.ln^2,lag+1)
m=summary(lm(mat[,1]~mat[,-1]))
SSR1=sum(residuals(lm(mat[,1]~mat[,-1]))^2)
SSR0=sum(residuals(lm(mat[,1]~1))^2)
stat=length(mat[,1])*(1-(SSR1/SSR0))
```

which gives $\chi^2$ = 43.5041.

If I apply the first statistic provided by @mpiktas and shown on page 102 of Tsay (2005):

$$F=\frac{(SSR_0-SSR_1)/m}{SSR_1/(T-2m-1)}$$

```
intc=read.table("http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/fts2/m-intc7303.txt",quote="\"")
intc.ln=log(1+intc$V2)
lag=12
mat=embed(intc.ln^2,lag+1)
m=summary(lm(mat[,1]~mat[,-1]))
SSR1=sum(residuals(lm(mat[,1]~mat[,-1]))^2)
SSR0=sum(residuals(lm(mat[,1]~1))^2)
stat=((SSR0-SSR1)/lag)/(SSR1/(length(mat[,1])-(2*lag)-1))
```

This version of the statistic gives $\chi^2$ = 3.837.

These are very different answers?  I have provided the residuals for the AR(5) model from SAS below:

```
c(0.14167,0.14019,-0.42499,0.0222,0.04388,-0.03157,0.00897, 
-0.04567,0.29171,-0.06735,0.05235,-0.04062,-0.18694, 
-0.2407,0.03766,-0.15011,0.11023,-0.30812,-0.02399, 
0.13434,0.05836,0.09368,-0.01832,-0.15669,-0.00127, 
0.19431,0.10366,-0.09682,-0.04597,0.07162,0.16411,-0.02181, 
-0.00459,-0.16325,-0.09615,-0.04581,0.10441,0.12845,-0.0398,
-0.03349,-0.01575,0.06923,-0.05006,-0.05827, 
-0.0317,0.08914,0.07323,0.06519,0.16141,0.0537,0.08213,
0.01073,-0.06628,0.01297,0.00622,-0.10171,0.05598,-0.05615, 
0.10322,-0.04991,-0.01223,-0.04975,-0.06043,0.01794, 
-0.00071,0.05425,-0.05462,0.01659,0.08656,0.02482,-0.04214, 
0.01221)
```

For lag 5, SAS gives $\chi^2$ = 1.105, `FinTS` gives $\chi^2$ = 3.189, and the F-statistic version gives $\chi^2$ = 0.560.

**References:**

Engle, R. F.  1982.  Autoregressive conditional heteroscedasticity with estimates of the variance of United Kingdom inflation.  Econometrica 50:987-1007.

Tsay, R. S.  2005.  Analysis of financial time series.  Second edition.  John Wiley & Sons, Inc., Hoboken, New Jersey, USA.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your data has small sample size. If you look at the original Engle article, the steps to calculate the statistic are the following:

1. Do initial regression and save residuals
2. Regress squared residuals on their lags.
3. Use $TR^2$ as a statistic, where $T$ is the sample size and $R^2$ is the R-squared from the second regression.

The statistic calculated in Tsay is F-statistic from the second regression:

$$F=\frac{(SSR_0-SSR_1)/m}{SSR_1/(T-2m-1)},$$

where $m$ is the number of lags in the second regression, $SSR_0$ is the sum of total squares and the $SSR_1$ is the sum of squared residuals from the second regression.

For comparison

$$TR^2=T\left(1-\frac{SSR_1}{SSR_0}\right)$$

So the statistics are different. I suspect that the p-values differ significantly for larger lags, because your sample size is small. This is just a guess, since you do not provide the data.

Comment: I have added some additional commentary regarding these two statistics in question. Thanks.